# how to solve mvc validation error

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

```
 public String Name {Get;Set;} 
 Public String LastName {Get;Set;} 
 Public String Age {Get;Set;} 
 [required]
 public Comment{Get;Set;}

        <body>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
        @html.textboxfor(m=>m.name)
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="submit">Search</input>
        </td>
        <tr>
        </table>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
        @html.textboxfor(m=>m.comment)
    </td>
 <td>
        <input type="submit">Save</input>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
        </body>
```

**When click On Button Model Valiadtion Apply On Comment but validation apply on coomnt when  Save Buuton Click Validation is data Annotation validation**

Comment: Your Question is not clear, please update your Question

Comment: Validation Work Only Click On Save button Click

Comment: can you add your entire html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to Use Jquery Unobstrusive validation for Instant Validation Like this;

Model Class

```
public class UserModel
{
   [Required(ErrorMessage ="Name is Mandatory")]
   public string FirstName {get;set;}
   [Required(ErrorMessage ="Last Name Field is Mandatory")] 
   Public string LastName {get;set;} 
   Public string Age {get;set;} 
   [required]
   public Comment{get;set;}
}
```

And in You CsHtml  File Please include Thes Libraries

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

After that Change Your View Code and Add `ValidateMessageFor` To show errors

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.FirstName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName, null, new { @class = "" })
```